# How to Load Global Varables in header into External Javascript FIle

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, global-variables

I have created meta-data keys on my Wordpress posts, as follows: prettyAd, prettyName, prettyLink. I want to take the value for each key and load it into a Global Variable in the header of my site.

I am setting Global variables in my WordPress Theme header as follows...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prettyAd = "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prettyAd', true); ?>";
    var prettyName = "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prettyName', true); ?>";
    var prettyLink = "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prettyLink', true); ?>";
</script>
```

Which outputs the following when the page is loaded...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prettyAd = "http://mydomainname.com/ad-placeholders/ad.png";
    var prettyName = "Pet Store Shop";
    var prettyLink = "http://mydomainname.com/advertise/";
</script>
```

After that, an external JavaScript file (prettyphoto.js - version 3.1) is loaded which I would like to access the variables set above.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/wpnavigator/scripts/prettyphoto.js"></script>
```

Once the above file has access to the variables I would like to load them into the following html where I have referenced them.

```
<p>
    Sponosor: <a href="var prettyLink" target="_blank">var prettyName</a>
</p>
<p>
    <a href="var prettyLink" target="_blank">
        <img src="var prettyAd" width="468" height="60" alt="Sponsors Ad" />
    </a>
</p>
```

From what I understand I will need to have the JavaScript compile the whole tag as i can not load the variables directly as the src and href values.

So what I am looking for help with is the following.

1. How do I call the global variables that have been set in the header.php into the prettyphoto.js file
2. How do I write a function that will use these variables and output the HTML shown above.
3. Is there a better way of doing this than with Global variables or are they the only way.

Comment: Have you tried alerting your global variables in your external js?  So long as it is below your <script> block, it should work.

Comment: Also, why not echo your global vars directly to your html?  Is there some reason your external js needs to handle these vars?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way would be like this in the html:

```
<p>
 Sponosor: <script type="text/javascript">document.write('<a href="' + prettyLink + '" target="_blank">' + prettyName + '</a>');</script>
</p>
```

However, if you need access in the script which was loaded, and you are inside of that script, then you could access it via the window

```
var LinkText = window["prettyName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) for this kind of thing. It has the advantage of wrapping your disparate js variables into one single global access point.

The tutorial here should get you started.
http://betterwp.net/wordpress-tips/script-localization/